# Next-Auth : defaultCookies is not defined

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm using next/auth version: 3.27.3
I suddenly got this error while running my app. Anyone encountered this?

```
error - unhandledRejection: ReferenceError: defaultCookies is not defined
    at C:\Users\MAGICSOFT Mike\Desktop\NEW MAGICSOFT\crd-prototype\node_modules\next-auth\dist\server\index.js:102:9
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NextAuthHandler (C:\Users\MAGICSOFT Mike\Desktop\NEW MAGICSOFT\crd-prototype\node_modules\next-auth\dist\server\index.js:67:10)
    at NextAuth (C:\Users\MAGICSOFT Mike\Desktop\NEW MAGICSOFT\crd-prototype\node_modules\next-auth\dist\server\index.js:299:10)
    at __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ (C:\Users\MAGICSOFT Mike\Desktop\NEW MAGICSOFT\crd-prototype\.next\server\pages\api\auth\[...nextauth].js:188:128)
    at Object.apiResolver (C:\Users\MAGICSOFT Mike\Desktop\NEW MAGICSOFT\crd-prototype\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils.js:101:15)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async DevServer.handleApiRequest (C:\Users\MAGICSOFT Mike\Desktop\NEW MAGICSOFT\crd-prototype\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:775:9)
    at async Object.fn (C:\Users\MAGICSOFT Mike\Desktop\NEW MAGICSOFT\crd-prototype\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:666:37)
```

Comment: Facing the same issue since last Friday. Everything works fine on localhost but once we deploy we get this error.

Comment: Same here. next-auth devs suggested to upgrade from v3 to v4. That is a hustle

Comment: Anybody knows what causes the error? Is it a must to upgrade to v4 or this can't be solved?

Comment: @AnargyrosStylidis It's most likely this change introduced in v3.29.4: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/commit/87f6f576b1f31249868991a2d1fecc4a9e4f5ce8#r75837858. You should pin your version to `3.29.3` until it's fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like changing the next-auth version on your package.json file solves this issue.

For my case, changing from version "^3.29.0" to "3.29.3" solved the issue.